# Can I use a bool type with XAML X:Static?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, markup-extensions

I am trying to make a menu item's visibility conditioned on the DEBUG macro. (It's a debug menu item and so should not be visible in a release build.) I am trying to follow the `x:Static` example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions

I have the following in my AppShell Class:

```
namespace myappname
{
    public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {

#if DEBUG
        public static readonly bool IsDebug = true;
#else
        public static readonly bool IsDebug = false;
#endif
```

In the AppShell XAML I have tried numerous variations of

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Debug" Icon="DebugCheckedTests_16x.png" IsVisible="{x:Static local:bool.IsDebug}">
```

But everything I have tried either gives me the error XFC0000   Cannot resolve type "bool" -- or some other error.

Am I way off base, or is bool not a valid type for x:Static? How do I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs you [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions#the-xstatic-markup-extension) what you are trying to accomplish comes under "a public static field", thus you need to specify the class where the field `IsDebug` is defined, in the docs example the class name is `AppConstants`, it is not a matter of "bool" type you can use any type as long as it is the type expected by the property.

```
xmlns:localRoot="clr-namespace:myappname"
```

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Debug" Icon="DebugCheckedTests_16x.png"
            IsVisible="{x:Static localRoot:AppShell.IsDebug}>
```

Comment: I think that is one of the many variants I tried. Yields XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "AppShell".

Comment: have you properly include the xaml namepace "local" ? something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"` YourNameSpace is the namespace where your AppShell class is defined.

Comment: I updated the code sample in the main post to show the AppShell class and its namespace.

Comment: And the XAML Shell that is the parent of the FlyoutItem in question includes xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myappname.Views".

Comment: I see that your "local" namespace = myappname.Views, while your AppShell is defined in myappname, please check my update.

Comment: Great minds think alike! I noticed that too. I solved it a different way. I moved the #if DEBUG/static bools into a relevant View page class and referenced it in the FlyoutItem as local:DebugPage.IsDebug. Thank you.